# Getting data from JSON

Tags: java, json, dictionary, hashmap, gson

I'm trying to get the values out of this JSON string but I'm having a hard time achieving this.

```
{"DebugLogId":"1750550","RequestId":"17505503","Result":
{"Code":"","DebugLogId":"1750550","Message":""},
    "Suggestions":[
        {"Ranking":"1","Score":"60","Title":"This is a test message 1"},
        {"Ranking":"2","Score":"60","Title":"This is a test message 2"}         
    ]}
```

What way would be easiest to access the data in 'Suggestions'? I'm using the GSON module. Ideally I would like to put it all in a HashMap.

Thanks for any help and/or suggestions!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: something I answered earlier today may help you out. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593569/how-to-parse-json-using-gson/6593800#6593800)

Answer (score 5):

Hope this helps:

App.java:

```
package sg.java.play_sof_json_6596072;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = "{\"DebugLogId\":\"1750550\",\"RequestId\":\"17505503\",\"Result\":{\"Code\":\"\",\"DebugLogId\":\"1750550\",\"Message\":\"\"},\"Suggestions\":[{\"Ranking\":\"1\",\"Score\":\"60\",\"Title\":\"This is a test message 1\"},{\"Ranking\":\"2\",\"Score\":\"60\",\"Title\":\"This is a test message 2\"}]}";

        Debug obj = (Debug) gson.fromJson(jsonString, Debug.class);

        System.out.println(obj.getSuggestionList().get(1).getTitle());

    }
}
```

Debug.java:

```
package sg.java.play_sof_json_6596072;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Debug {
    @SerializedName("DebugLogId")
    private String debugLogId;
    @SerializedName("RequestId")
    private String requestId;
    @SerializedName("Result")
    private Result result;
    @SerializedName("Suggestions")
    private List<Suggestion> suggestionList;

    /**
     * @return the debugLogId
     */
    public final String getDebugLogId() {
        return this.debugLogId;
    }

    /**
     * @param debugLogId the debugLogId to set
     */
    public final void setDebugLogId(String debugLogId) {
        this.debugLogId = debugLogId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the requestId
     */
    public final String getRequestId() {
        return this.requestId;
    }

    /**
     * @param requestId the requestId to set
     */
    public final void setRequestId(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the result
     */
    public final Result getResult() {
        return this.result;
    }

    /**
     * @param result the result to set
     */
    public final void setResult(Result result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    /**
     * @return the suggestionList
     */
    public final List<Suggestion> getSuggestionList() {
        return this.suggestionList;
    }

    /**
     * @param suggestionList the suggestionList to set
     */
    public final void setSuggestionList(List<Suggestion> suggestionList) {
        this.suggestionList = suggestionList;
    }

}
```

Result.java:

```
package sg.java.play_sof_json_6596072;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Result {
    @SerializedName("Code")
    private String code;
    @SerializedName("DebugLogId")
    private String debugLogId;
    @SerializedName("Message")
    private String messahe;

    /**
     * @return the code
     */
    public final String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    /**
     * @param code the code to set
     */
    public final void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    /**
     * @return the debugLogId
     */
    public final String getDebugLogId() {
        return this.debugLogId;
    }

    /**
     * @param debugLogId the debugLogId to set
     */
    public final void setDebugLogId(String debugLogId) {
        this.debugLogId = debugLogId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the messahe
     */
    public final String getMessahe() {
        return this.messahe;
    }

    /**
     * @param messahe the messahe to set
     */
    public final void setMessahe(String messahe) {
        this.messahe = messahe;
    }

}
```

Suggestion.java:

```
package sg.java.play_sof_json_6596072;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Suggestion {
    @SerializedName("Ranking")
    private String ranking;
    @SerializedName("Score")
    private String score;
    @SerializedName("Title")
    private String title;

    /**
     * @return the ranking
     */
    public final String getRanking() {
        return this.ranking;
    }

    /**
     * @param ranking the ranking to set
     */
    public final void setRanking(String ranking) {
        this.ranking = ranking;
    }

    /**
     * @return the score
     */
    public final String getScore() {
        return this.score;
    }

    /**
     * @param score the score to set
     */
    public final void setScore(String score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    /**
     * @return the title
     */
    public final String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    /**
     * @param title the title to set
     */
    public final void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks man! This worked just perfect!

What does the annotation '@SerializedName' do?

Thanks again!

Comment: It provides a mapping between the key used in the JSON string, and the attribute in your Java class that you wish to map into.

Comment: I have no idea why someone would down vote your and my answers.  I'll upvote this.  It's a decent answer.

Comment: Just a quick note to clarify this useful answer I upvoted.. The syntax for using the @SerializedName annotation is vital when you need to alias a json field named, say, 'class' which is a reserved keyword in Java. But you certainly don't need to annotate every class member. IF the jason object field names are legal and you can live with field names that don't exactly match your own coding conventions, just name your object members the same as the JSON field names.

Answer (score 1):

I'm recommend you to use flexjson library http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/
IMHO, it more simple and usable library. I has used GSON first time, but then switched all my projects to flexjson instead of GSON.

Comment: Thank you Eugene! That looks interesting. Will also have a look at that next time I deal with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [standard json classes](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) in android:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject("your string");
JSONArray a = o.getJSONArray("Suggestions");
int i = 0;
while ( i < a.length())
{
    o = a.getJSONObject(i);
    //do something with o, like o.getString("Title") ...
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Wieux, but not using Android.

Comment: It's not an Android specific API; Android uses the json.org API which can also be found here: http://www.json.org/java/index.html

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally I would like to put it all in a HashMap.

If you can switch libraries, [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) can achieve that with just one line of code.

```
Map map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Map.class);
```

This would deserialize any JSON object into a `HashMap`, composed of just Java SE components.  I haven't yet seen another Java-to/from-JSON library that can do that.

The same can be accomplished with Gson, but it requires a few more lines of code.  Here's one such solution.

```
JsonElement je = new JsonParser().parse(json);  
JsonObject jo = je.getAsJsonObject();
Map<String, Object> map = createMapFromJsonObject(jo);

// ...

static Map<String, Object> createMapFromJsonObject(  
    JsonObject jo)  
{  
  Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
  for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jo.entrySet())  
  {  
    String key = entry.getKey();  
    JsonElement value = entry.getValue();  
    map.put(key, getValueFromJsonElement(value));  
  }  
  return map;  
}  

static Object getValueFromJsonElement(JsonElement je)  
{  
  if (je.isJsonObject())  
  {  
    return createMapFromJsonObject(je.getAsJsonObject());  
  }  
  else if (je.isJsonArray())  
  {  
    JsonArray array = je.getAsJsonArray();  
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(array.size());  
    for (JsonElement element : array)  
    {  
      list.add(getValueFromJsonElement(element));  
    }  
    return list;  
  }  
  else if (je.isJsonNull())  
  {  
    return null;  
  }  
  else // must be primitive  
  {  
    JsonPrimitive p = je.getAsJsonPrimitive();  
    if (p.isBoolean()) return p.getAsBoolean();  
    if (p.isString()) return p.getAsString();  
    // else p is number, but don't know what kind  
    String s = p.getAsString();  
    try  
    {  
      return new BigInteger(s);  
    }  
    catch (NumberFormatException e)  
    {  
      // must be a decimal  
      return new BigDecimal(s);  
    }  
  }  
}
```

(I copied this code from my blog post at http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/06/gson-v-jackson.html.)