# Java Gson - help me parse my JSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm new to GSON and am really struggling to parse this data:

```
{
   "0":{
      "county":"Carlow",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"52.72465",
         "lng":"-6.92963"
      }
   },
   "1":{
      "county":"Cavan",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.9011",
         "lng":"-7.34436"
      }
   },
   "2":{
      "county":"Clare",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"52.73629",
         "lng":"-8.97583"
      }
   },
   "3":{
      "county":"Cork",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"51.78823",
         "lng":"-8.46771"
      }
   },
   "4":{
      "county":"Dublin North County",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"51.78823",
         "lng":"-6.174316"
      }
   },
   "5":{
      "county":"Dublin South County",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.272605",
         "lng":"-6.166077"
      }
   },
   "6":{
      "county":"Dublin 1",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.62798",
         "lng":"-8.188635"
      }
   },
   "7":{
      "county":"Dublin 2",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.352996",
         "lng":"-6.24637"
      }
   },
   "8":{
      "county":"Dublin 3",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.338166",
         "lng":"-6.336515"
      }
   },
   "9":{
      "county":"Dublin 4",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.368377",
         "lng":"-6.18873"
      }
   },
   "10":{
      "county":"Dublin 5",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.311391",
         "lng":"-6.219978"
      }
   },
   "11":{
      "county":"Dublin 6",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.385938",
         "lng":"-6.193697"
      }
   },
   "12":{
      "county":"Dublin 7",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.349219",
         "lng":"-6.289244"
      }
   },
   "13":{
      "county":"Dublin 8",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.350221",
         "lng":"-6.282517"
      }
   },
   "14":{
      "county":"Dublin 9",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.351576",
         "lng":"-6.284523"
      }
   },
   "15":{
      "county":"Dublin 10",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.3866058",
         "lng":"-6.23542"
      }
   },
   "16":{
      "county":"Dublin 11",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.342557",
         "lng":"-6.358278"
      }
   },
   "17":{
      "county":"Dublin 12",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.34968",
         "lng":"-6.24723"
      }
   },
   "18":{
      "county":"Dublin 13",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.33d3918"
      }
   },
   "19":{
      "county":"Dublin 15",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.382076",
         "lng":"-6.366707"
      }
   },
   "20":{
      "county":"Dublin 16",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.382076",
         "lng":"-6.366707"
      }
   },
   "21":{
      "county":"Dublin 17",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.310775",
         "lng":"-6.242981"
      }
   },
   "22":{
      "county":"Dublin 18",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.407485",
         "lng":"-6.205215"
      }
   },
   "23":{
      "county":"Dublin 20",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.407485",
         "lng":"-6.205215"
      }
   },
   "24":{
      "county":"Dublin 22",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.355403",
         "lng":"-6.371452"
      }
   },
   "25":{
      "county":"Dublin 24",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.299391",
         "lng":"-6.390263"
      }
   },
   "26":{
      "county":"Galway",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.17477",
         "lng":"-9.03625"
      }
   },
   "27":{
      "county":"Kerry",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"52.1554",
         "lng":"-9.69269"
      }
   },
   "28":{
      "county":"Kildare",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.159829",
         "lng":"-6.908998"
      }
   },
   "29":{
      "county":"Kilkenny",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"52.54296",
         "lng":"-7.23175"
      }
   },
   "30":{
      "county":"Laois",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"52.88571",
         "lng":"-7.31689"
      }
   },
   "31":{
      "county":"Lietrim",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.88815",
         "lng":"-8.07495"
      }
   },
   "32":{
      "county":"Limerick",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"52.55465",
         "lng":"-8.65448"
      }
   },
   "33":{
      "county":"Longford",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.61695",
         "lng":"-7.77832"
      }
   },
   "34":{
      "county":"Louth",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.92699",
         "lng":"-6.53893"
      }
   },
   "35":{
      "county":"Mayo",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.74546",
         "lng":" -9.29169"
      }
   },
   "36":{
      "county":"Meath",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.45371",
         "lng":" -6.7923"
      }
   },
   "37":{
      "county":"Monaghan",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"54.13831",
         "lng":"-6.97083"
      }
   },
   "38":{
      "county":"Offaly",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.15501",
         "lng":"-7.74261"
      }
   },
   "39":{
      "county":"Roscommon",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.5762",
         "lng":" -8.19855"
      }
   },
   "40":{
      "county":"Sligo",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"54.16887",
         "lng":"-8.47321"
      }
   },
   "41":{
      "county":"Tipperary",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"52.36386",
         "lng":"-8.16833"
      }
   },
   "42":{
      "county":"Waterford",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"52.10988",
         "lng":"-7.12189"
      }
   },
   "43":{
      "county":"Westmeath",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.34727",
         "lng":"-7.46521"
      }
   },
   "44":{
      "county":"Wexford",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"52.2278",
         "lng":"-6.48193"
      }
   },
   "45":{
      "county":"Wicklow",
      "coords":{
         "lat":"53.08286",
         "lng":"-6.07904"
      }
   }
}
```

Here's what I have sofar, but I think it's wrong...

```
public class GPSObject {
        private String county;
        private Coords coords;
        GPSObject() {
            // no-args constructor
        }
        public class Coords{
            public String lat;
            public String lng;
            public Coords() {
              // No args constructor for B
            }
        } 
    }


Gson gson=new Gson();
GPSObject obj2=gson.fromJson(response,GPSObject.class);
```

Here's an error I'm getting:

```
> 07-08 09:26:08.731:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26763): FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main 07-08 09:26:08.731:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26763):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: No-args
> constructor for class
> ie.clarity.ShowJobsOnMap$GPSObject
> does not exist. Register an
 > InstanceCreator with Gson for this
> type to fix this problem. 07-08
> 09:26:08.731:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26763): atcom.google.gson.MappedObjectConstructor.constructWithNoArgConstructor(MappedObjectConstructor.java:64)
> 07-08 09:26:08.731:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26763):     at
> com.google.gson.MappedObjectConstructor.construct(MappedObjectConstructor.java:53)
> 07-08 09:26:08.731:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26763):     at
>         com.google.gson.JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.constructTarget(JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.java:41)
> 07-08 09:26:08.731:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26763):     at
> com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.getTarget(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:56)
> 07-08 09:26:08.731:
> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26763):     at
> com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:101)
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to parse this JSON without using the GSON and I was able to parse this JSON string. Please try this also as a alternative solution. I am detailing snippet of the code that I have used to parse this string:

```
for(int i=0; i<46; i++){
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject   =   new JSONObject(<string to be parsed>);
                String first            =   jsonObject.getString(Integer.toString(i));
                JSONObject jsonObject1  =   new JSONObject(first);
                String country          =   jsonObject1.getString("county");
                System.out.println("country="+country);
                String cod              =   jsonObject1.getString("coords");
                JSONObject jsonObject2  =   new JSONObject(cod);
                String lat              =   jsonObject2.getString("lat");
                System.out.println("lat="+lat);
                String lng              =   jsonObject2.getString("lng");
                System.out.println("lng="+lng);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was transfixed on Gson.

Answer (score 2):

`No-args constructor for class ie.clarity.ShowJobsOnMap$GPSObject does not exist` indicates the constructor is not found, most probably because it's not visible in your case. Add the `public` keyword to the constructor: `public GPSObject() { ... }` instead of `GPSObject() { ... }`

Edit: the `GPSObject` class seems to be nested in `ShowJobsOnMap` as indicated by the error message.
You now pass `GPSObject.class` to GSON, however to construct an object of a non-static nested class, you first need an object of the enclosing class. In order to solve that, you'd have to declare the nested class static and thus remove the special relationship between the nested and the enclosing class. The enclosing class then just has the function of a namespace for the nested class' point of view.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I have my GPSObject defined as: ```public class GPSObject {
  public String county;
  public Coords coords;
  GPSObject() {
   // no-args constructor
  }
  public class Coords{
      public String lat;
      public String lng;
      public Coords() {
        // No args constructor for B
      }
  } 
 }``` Everything is public as far as I can see.

Comment: Not concerning you actual problem, but just an advice, I would read the coordinates from json as Double and store them in your class as GeoPoint. If my thoughts are wrong, correction is welcome ;)

Comment: @Eamorr - No, the GPSObject constructor isn't public but has default access. Thus it's not visible to GSON.

Comment: @Thomas: made the constructor public. Here's the error I'm getting now: ```07-08 09:45:40.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27012): java.lang.RuntimeException: No-args constructor for class ie.clarity.ShowJobsOnMap$GPSObject does not exist. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type to fix this problem.```

Comment: @Eamorr: I also suspect the `GPSObject` class is nested. Make it `public static`, I'll update my post with an explanation.

Comment: Yes, I moved it into it's own file and made it public static. I've moved on a step now... However, now I'm getting this error ```07-08 09:59:14.491: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27193): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message``` when I try to do ```Gson gson=new Gson();
                   GPSObject obj2=gson.fromJson(response,GPSObject.class);
                   Log.i("EOH",obj2.county);``` I don't think the structure of my GPSObject is correct for the given JSON.

Comment: @Eamorr - Is `county` public as well? Do you have a setter for that field? Additionaly, since your data is an array of GPSObjects, I suspect `gson.fromJson(response,GPSObject.class);` returns an array instead of a single object - i'm no GSON expert though (using JSON simple)

Comment: Yes, it's public as well. I think I'm going to use JSONObject instead of Gson. You don't need a template class...

Comment: Two Corrections (if using the latest release of Gson): 1. Gson does not need anything to be public, in order to access it.  This includes constructors.  2. Gson can deserialize to instances of inner classes very easily, without custom processing to explicitly handle the enclosing class instantiation -- Gson will take care of it.  I posted an example of this at http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/06/gson-v-jackson.html.  (Search for the "Inner Classes - Deserialization" section.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one simple approach using Gson.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type gpsMapType = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, GPSObject>>() {}.getType();
    Map<Integer, GPSObject> gpsObjects = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), gpsMapType);
    System.out.println("GPSObjects Count: " + gpsObjects.size());
    for (Integer key : gpsObjects.keySet())
    {
      GPSObject gpsObject = gpsObjects.get(key);
      System.out.printf("%d: {county: %s, coords:{lat:%s, %s}}\n", 
        key, gpsObject.county, gpsObject.coords.lat, gpsObject.coords.lng);
    }
  }
}

class GPSObject
{
  String county;
  Coords coords;
}

class Coords
{
  String lat;
  String lng;
}
```

Output:

```
GPSObjects Count: 46
0: {county: Carlow, coords:{lat:52.72465, -6.92963}}
1: {county: Cavan, coords:{lat:53.9011, -7.34436}}
2: {county: Clare, coords:{lat:52.73629, -8.97583}}
3: {county: Cork, coords:{lat:51.78823, -8.46771}}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this may help you [Getting data from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596072/getting-data-from-json/6596435#6596435)

Can you post the codes of your classes in your main post?

Comment: Hi Chin, thanks for the response. I think I should be using JSONObject rather than Gson - it's a bit simpler and I don't have to define a data structure in a separate class?

Comment: Hi Eamorr, the "beauty" of GSON is the boiler code that you need not write to be able to map data from your JSON string to your domain object (Car, Bus, Person). It also depends on your views or needs, some would like to have domain objects, and have GSON map the data for them, some would rather have generic objects like JSONObject.