# GSON: Missing fields when converting Java objects to JSON with gson.toJson

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using the [GSON 1.7.1](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library to create a JSON representation of a number of Java objects. This works well, however when the class extends eg Vector< String > then the fields are missing from the output.

**Actual Output:**

```
[
  "String 1",
  "String 2"
]
```

**Required/Expected output:**
I would like both the contents of the new object's fields to be displayed as well as the contents of the Vector I'm extending. eg something like this...

```
{
  "extraInfo": "Extra Info",
  "vector": [
     "String 1",
     "String 2"
  ]
}
```

I'm adding this to existing code so I don't have the option of changing the class structure from extending type Vector< String > to containing a field of type Vector< String >

**Here's the example source code...**

```
import java.util.Vector;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class ExtendedStringVector extends Vector<String>{

    private String extraInfo = "";

    public String toString(){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String jsonOutput = gson.toJson(this);
        return jsonOutput;
    }

    public void setExtraInfo(String test) {
         this.extraInfo = test;
    }

    public String getExtraInfo() {
        return extraInfo;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExtendedStringVector esv = new ExtendedStringVector();
        esv.add("String 1");
        esv.add("String 2");
        esv.setExtraInfo("Extra Info");
        System.out.println(esv.toString());
    }
}
```

There is some documentantion [here](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Gener) which looks like it is close to what I need however it doesn't cover my case.

Is there an easy way to get the output I expect? Have I missed a simple settings or type parameter?

Comment: Do you have to use Gson?  Or can you change JSON-to/from-Java libraries?

Comment: No, I don't have to use GSON. GSON was extremely easy to use/setup and does everything I need apart from the problem in this question. If anyone else knows of other JSON to/from libraries that can cope with this case then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your required output is an invalid JSON structure.

Something like this is valid:

```
{
  "extraInfo": "Extra Info",
  "vector" : [
     "String 1",
     "String 2"
  ]
}
```

To achieve this, you need an object that composes of a String object, and a list (can be vector or array or List) of String objects.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596072/getting-data-from-json).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'm adding this to existing code so I don't have the option of changing the class from extending type Vector< String > to containing a field of type Vector< String >. Are there any other GSON options that can be changed?

Answer (score 1):

I looked through a few Java-to/from-JSON libraries, and didn't see anything that had a built-in feature like what you're after.  Custom serialization/deserialization is necessary.